# What is $f$ in $f(x)+f(1-x)=f(x^2)$?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, functional-equations

> Find all $f(x)$ such that $f(x)+f(1-x)=f(x^2)$ is satisfied

This is a question I made up, and my solution is as follows:

> Let $x=1$ (or $x=0$), then $f(0)+f(1)=f(1)$ which means that $f(0)=0$. Substitute $-x$ for $x$. We get that $$f(x)+f(1-x)=f(-x)+f(1+x)=f(x^2)$$Note that substituting $x+1$ into the original functional equation yields $f(x+1)+f(-x)=f((x+1)^2)$, meaning that $$f(x^2)=f((x+1)^2)$$Thus we need to find a function that is the same when the input is the square of an integer. Two such functions are $$\frac{a\lfloor\sqrt{x}\rfloor}{\sqrt{x}}\text{ and }\frac{a\lceil\sqrt{x}\rceil}{\sqrt{x}}$$Where $a$ is any real number.

I am not sure how to prove that these are (not) the only functions that solve the functional equation. (The case $f(x)=0$ is included in the two functions when $a=0$). So what are the other functions, if there are any?

Edit: The functions in my solution are only true when $x$ is an integer (meaning that, according to @BrunoB's comment, the functions aren't solutions), so this means that $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. I would like to see a solution for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or maybe even for $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Will $\sin (2\pi \sqrt{x})$ be a solution?

Comment: @Vasili Yes! Also $a\sin^2(2\pi\sqrt{x})$ and maybe $a\sin^a(2\pi\sqrt{x})$

Comment: Are you considering $f$ as a function from the integers to the reals or can $x$ be any real?

Comment: @user1172706 Any number actually.

Comment: @Vasili I meant $a\sin^b(2\pi\sqrt{x})$ I messed up.

Comment: Also, $f(x) \equiv 0$ is a solution :)

Comment: @Vasili (and OP) Why would $\sin (2 pi \sqrt{x} )$ be a solution? It doesn't satisfy $f(x) + f(1-x) = f(x^2)$ (eg [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sin+%282pi+%28x%29%5E.5%29+%2B+sin+%282pi+%281-x%29%5E.5%29+%3D+sin+%282pi+x%29)), nor of $ f(x^2) = f( (x+1))^2 $ (for non-integers).

Comment: @KamalSaleh Note that several of your implications are 1 directional only. EG The functions that you mentioned at the end may be "same when the input is the square of an integer", but do not satisfy $f(x^2 ) = f( (x+1)^2)$. Can you please clarify what is it that you want? 1/ Solutions to the original functional identity $f(x) + f(1-x) = f(x^2)$ 2/ Solutions to $f(x^2) = f( (x+1)^2) $, 3/ Solutions to "function that is the same when the input is the square of an integer". $\quad$ For example, the set of solutions to 3 is "f(n^2) = constant for integers n, f(r) = anything else for non integers".

Comment: For the original equation, just to clarify: since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x^2) = f((x+1)^2)$, $f$ will be zero on all $n^2$s, and then you can put any function you want over the positive integers that aren't perfect squares due to the difference of domains between $n$ and $1-n$ and the fact that you only get $f(n) = -f(1-n)$ afterwards. So it'll be pretty uneventful with just integers as the domain. If the domain is changed to be the reals, then it'll be another story, especially (but not limited to) if continuity is involved.

Comment: @BrunoB I see, I will edit. Thanks!

Comment: youy will not be able to define the set of all expressions that define $f$

Comment: The two functions you found don't seem to fit the criteria for $f(x)+f(1-x) = f(x^2)$ like you can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hev0qdba3o).